# How can I set a specific value in an array at one index equal to a value in another array at a different index in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, cs50

So I am learning to program, and our current assignment involves the creation of a program that creates a substitution cipher given a key the user inputs.
Yet the issue I come across is this: I can't set the value of a value in one array to **be** that of another array. This is specifically with two strings.
This issue is specific to this area in the **encrypt** function:

```
for(int i=0; i<strlen(plaintext);i++)
    {
        for(int x=i+1;x<strlen(key);x++)
            {
                if(plaintext[i]==alphabets[x])
                {
                    outputArray[i]=key[x];
                }
            }
    }
```

Here is my source code for reference:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int compareInt(const void *pa, const void *pb);
bool keyCheck(string key);
int encrypt(string plaintext, string key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key=argv[1];
    string plaintext;
    if(keyCheck(argv[1]))
    {
        
        
        plaintext = get_string("Plaintext:");
        //printf("Ciphertext: %s", encrypt(plaintext, key));
        encrypt(plaintext, key);
    }



}

bool keyCheck(string key)
{
    bool valid = false;
    //convert key to lower
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(key);i++)
    {
        key[i]=tolower(key[i]);
    }

    //check key length
    if(strlen(key)!=26)
    {
        printf("Please provide a key with legnth of 26 Alphabetic characters\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int results = 0;
        int n = sizeof(key)/sizeof(string);
        qsort(key, n, sizeof(int), compareInt);
        for (int i = 0; i<=strlen(key); i++)
        {
            if(key[i+1]==key[i])
            {
                results=1;
            }
        }


        /*
        for(int i=0;i<=strlen(key);i++)
        {
            for(int x=i+1;x<=strlen(key);x++)
            {
                if(key[i]==key[x])
                {
                    results+=1;
                }
            }
        }
        */
        if (results>0)
        {
            printf("Please provide a key with no duplicate characters\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Key is valid, proceed\n");
            valid = true;
        }
    }

    return valid;
}

int encrypt(string plaintext, string key)
{
    char outputArray[strlen(plaintext)];
    string alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    //match the plaintext values to a character in the alphabets string
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(plaintext);i++)
    {
        for(int x=i+1;x<strlen(key);x++)
            {
                if(plaintext[i]==alphabets[x])
                {
                    outputArray[i]=key[x];
                }
            }
    }
    
    printf("\n%c",*outputArray);
    

    return 0;
}


int compareInt(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const int *p1 = pa;
    const int *p2 = pb;
    return *p1 - *p2;
}
```

Comment: `int n = sizeof(key)/sizeof(string)` will return 1 yes?  They are the same type.  Then the `qsort` has a random `sizeof(int)`  - where'd that come from?  And `char outputArray[strlen(plaintext)]` is not really legal (it uses a compiler extension called variable length arrays VLAs to hide dynamic memory allocation, but in this case it actually slightly harmless...)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but presumably you need to compare `plaintext[i]` with each of `alphabets[0]` through to `alphabets[25]` inclusive, and use the index of the matching entry in `alphabets` to select an element from `key` somehow. You also need to deal with the case where it doesn't match anything in `alphabets`.

Comment: In truth, if you can't use a debugger, you should print out `plaintext[i]` and `alphabets[x]` right before comparing them to understand why the assignment is never happening.  I bet that a match is not happening and your code is therefore not copying.

Comment: You should probably declare `outputArray` as `char *outputArray[strlen(plaintext) + 1];`, add a null terminator to the end, and print it as a string.

Comment: @IanAbbott You are correct, that is the exact intent.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I didn't realize it returns 1, thank you! Also, that sizeof(int) was a mistype, I was following along a video on how to use Qsort. Also, I'm not really that familiar with "VLAs" or "dynamic memory allocation", could you link something to help me learn. If you couldn't tell, Im on week two of CS50 and a bit new to this.

Comment: ceaser cipher is *not* encryption.  Change "encrypt" to "encode".

Comment: Why not just take ascii value of each letter, subtract starting value of the alphabet and take the char from the key at that index: `outputArray[i] = key[plaintext[i] - 'a'];`?

Comment: @WENDYN  could you elaborate further?

Comment: If I understand your encryption correctly you just shuffle which letter is which,
`key` is a lookup table, character that would be on position of letter `'a'` will be a different character, right?
So I can take the ASCII value as a position(index) `plaintext[i]` and retrieve a value from that array `key` at that index `key[plaintext[i]]`, but in ASCII table the alphabet has some offset so you also need to subtract it. `key[plaintext[i] - 'a']`